# How can I scale symbol size by a data attribute in R lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to scale symbol size by a data attribute using Lattice. In the example, I am conditioning on Month. There are two groups ('Ellipse'), each has three x-y observations made at Hours 1,2, and 3. It's a point & line graph, and I want to make the symbols for each Ellipse increment in size according to Hour, to indicate the direction in which time is incrementing. In the xyplot code below, I have added 'cex=d$Hour', but this just assigns different symbol sizes to the two Ellipses.

```
d <- data.table(expand.grid(Hour=1:3, Month=1:3, Ellipse=1:2))
d[, x := c(rnorm(9, mean=1, sd=1),rnorm(9, mean=2, sd=1.5))]
d[, y := c(rnorm(9, mean=1, sd=1),rnorm(9, mean=2, sd=2))]

xyplot(y ~ x|Month, d, type=c('l','p'), group = Ellipse,
    cex = d$Hour,
    auto.key=list(title="Ellipse", corner=c(0.8,0.8)))
```

[image: Example showing symbol size scaled by Ellipse instead of Hour]

Comment: Why are you using lattice? First of all, you need to ensure that `Month` and `Ellipse` are factors. Then you need to supply a panel function (should involve `panel.superpose`). I didn't manage to make it work but I've decided ten years ago not to bother with lattice.

Comment: Can you provide code in ggplot2 then?

Comment: Sure that's easy: `ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = Ellipse)) + geom_point(aes(size = Hour)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ Month, ncol = 2)` Ensure that `Ellipse` is a factor. You should read some ggplot2 tutorials.

Comment: SethW.Bigelow, I removed the [tag:data.table] tag: even though you are using `data.table` to create the sample data, that could just as easily have been `base::data.frame` or `tibble::tibble` for the same `xyplot` question. If I'm wrong in this interpretation, my apologies. I hope Roland's code resolves your question, I think it's a good way to get what I think you're asking for. Transitioning to `ggplot2` from `lattice` is likely just a little less difficult than from base `graphics::`, but it's still a bit of work ... but it is worth it (imho). Good luck on that journey!

Comment: I'd modify Roland's code per his comment ... `ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(Ellipse))) + ...`. At that point the biggest difference that I can see is that ggplot2 defaults to `shape=16` (base R's `pch=16`) which is a filled circle. You can go back to the empty circle with `... + geom_point(aes(size = Hour), shape=1) + ...` if that is important to you.

Comment: ... and lastly, if having the legend _inside_ the figure is important too, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18063447/3358272 and try `+ theme(legend.position = c(0.75, 0.2))` or `+ theme(legend.position = c(0.75, 0.2), legend.direction = "horizontal")`.

Comment: Thanks for ggplot2 suggestions Roland and R2Evans. I almost get what I need if I add group=factor(Ellipse), and make Hour a factor also. The only problem is that ggplot2 is connecting the symbols from left to right rather than in the order (Hour 1, Hour 2, Hour 3). E.g., Sometimes the line from Hour 1 is connected to Hour 3 then to Hour 2.

Comment: You should really ask a separate question regarding ggplot2. I suggest you delete this question. There are very few people still using lattice. Here is how to solve that last issue: `setorder(d, Hour); d[, c("x1", "y1") := shift(.(x, y), -1), keyby = .(Month, Ellipse)]; ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(Ellipse))) + geom_point(aes(size = factor(Hour))) + geom_segment(aes(xend = x1, yend = y1)) + facet_wrap(~ Month, ncol = 2)`

Comment: Roland, this latest ggplot2 code produces the result I am looking for. I can delete the lattice question. Should I then ask/answer the question framed as a ggplot2 question, or just drop it?